# Azure Virtual Machine not accessible after RDP port changed

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, rdp

I've changed RDP port to 8080 in registry on my Azure Virtual Machine (Windows Server). Now it is not accessible from outside, I cant connect it.

Azure VM is managed by Resource Manager (not Classic VM).

**UPDATE:**

Turning secuiruty rules so allow all not helped.
[image]

Comment: I can't quite imagine why you did that, but... What about your inbound security rules? Did you change the inbound rule to allow port 8080?

Comment: @davidmakogon, In Windows? No. Is this the end?

Comment: What do you mean, "*Is this the end?*" And no, not Windows. In Azure.

Comment: @davidmakogon, No. I don't know how to do it. I mean I think this can be a deadlock if windows firewall denies 8080 inbound traffic and rdpport is 8080. I'm not so expirienced in networking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've changed RDP port to 8080 in registry on my Azure Virtual Machine
>   (Windows Server)

We can use CustomScriptextension to **check** if RDP listening on port 8080.

`netstat -ant | findstr "8080"`
[image]

If your port not listening on Port 8080, we may need to restart RDP service.

If RDP listening on port 8080, we can use CustomScriptextension to **disable** windows firewall.
`netsh advfirewall set allprofiles state off`

About Extension, we create a ps1 file with the command, and upload it via Azure portal.

[image]

Comment: I've disabled firewall and successfully connected to the VM. Custom Script Extension is very useful. Thank you, Jason!

Answer (score 1):

Azure has to know to allow traffic through to your VM. By default, on a Windows VM, only RDP is open. But you (for some reason) changed the RDP port in Windows Server. You need to do this with the network interface as well, via the VM settings (which has nothing to do with Windows itself):

- Via Settings, go to Network Interfaces
- Select your network interface and go to Network Security Group
- From network security group, add an inbound rule for port 8080 (or modify the existing RDP rule to be port 8080).

Comment: thanks for your help, but still no success. I've allowed all ports in secuirity group, but VM still not avaliable, see update.

Comment: @AsValeO - Are you changing the port because you think it will make your site more secure?  Or because you are trying to get around outbound firewall rules at your company?

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch, I am now at the hotel. I can browsing internet, but my default rdp connection with 3389 port just not working here. I decided that hotel's network secuirity rules deny traffic through 3389 port.

Comment: @AsValeO - more than likely, they are blocking nearly all ports, and using an outbound web proxy server, so you cannot directly connect to anything.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch, ok now I got it. But I still cannot connect this VM even through my phone's mobile network after changing the port. So the question is not closed.

Answer (score 1):

It used to be possible to change your RDP port in Classic portal using endpoints. but in RM portal you cannot change your RDP port.

If you are trying to secure your box or by pass the security firewall to connect to your box, I recommend using Azure Load Balancer NAT rules, you can create a NAT rule to translate a custom port to 3389, and then you can only allow connectivity from LB to your VM, this a trick I use when I want to by pass the corporate's firewall, for example port 443.

Make sure you attach the LB to your VM from the NAT rule section

Comment: I've investigated Load Balancer. Now I understand that I shouldn't change RPD port on Windows, Load Balancer was the clue. Thank you, Alex.a!

Answer (score 1):

**To access any port from public ip client -**

Enable port in Azure firewall (if installed)

Enable Port in Network Security Group (add inbound rule) rule like 8080 -> 8080 or rule like  80 -> 8080

Enable Port in Windows Firewall of VM (on azure) -- most important if port is other than 80 and 443. - e.g. 8080, 8090 etc..