# Access vm local website without dns

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have a windows server 2012 vm (from azure) with a web node.js app running on it in port 3000.

I want to access that website from my computer, how can I do that?

Comment: Have you set up an inbound network security rule yet? Lots of questions (and answers) about this exact thing. Such as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43097145/272109).

Comment: You need to make sure you can reach 3000 from outside world (firewall rules).

Comment: I know how to open the port, my question is just as simple as "What should I type in the url?"

Answer (score 0):

> What should I type in the url

we can type in the URL with **Public IP address**, like http://publicipaddress:3000

Also we can set FQDN for this VM, so we can type in the URL with **FQDN**, like http://jasontest321.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com:3000

We can set FQDN in the public IP address via azure portal.
[image]

Answer (score -1):

your URL should be something like http://Azure URL or Public IP Address:3000 or  URL or Public IP Address:3000